# remove padding in jumbotron bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding

How to remove the default padding from jumbotron bootstrap 3? I am trying to set `padding-top:5px;` in jumbotron div. But there is some default padding, how to remove it?

Comment: try `padding-top:5px !important;` ,it will override the exhisting

Comment: **NO!!!** don't try `!important`. Not unless there is no other way.

Comment: If the base class does not have !important.. DO NOT USE IT IN your custom stylesheet. Don't force it to override. Apply !important only if the original bootstrap class has property with !important. Just orverride it in custom.css. That's it!

Comment: Better use a "well"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that the CSS selector's specificity for jumbotron would be greater than the one you are applying.

You can read more about the CSS [Selector Specificity here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

You can add an ID to your jumbotron, and style that,

```
#jumbo {
  padding: 5px;
}
```