# Can't override the margin between nav and jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Problem: space between `.nav` and `.jumbotron` in bootstrap.

what did I do: override the bootstrap.css , override `.jumbotron{margin-bottom:0px}`, it's not working.

What I've found: it works well when I debug it in the original file.

[couldn't work in override css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psC7w.png)

[work well in original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsWJx.png)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="top-header">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <img src="image/name.png" alt="">
        <h2>Curiosity Creative</h2>
    </div><!--Jumbotron-->
  </div><!--top-header-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#displayItem" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
         </div><!--navbar-header-->
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="displayItem">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="home active">
                    <a href="index.html"><i></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="me">
                    <a href="aboutMe.html"><i></i>AboutMe</a></li>
                    <li class="blog">
                    <a href="Blog.html"><i></i>Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="contact">
                    <a href="Contact.html"><i></i>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div> <!-- collapse navbar-collapse-->      
    </div><!--container -->
  </nav><!--nav-->      
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body{
background: url("../image/body_bg.jpg");
overflow: scroll;
}
div{
   position:relative;
 }
.top-header{
   background-color: white;
 }
.jumbotron {
    background-color:transparent !important; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
 }
.jumbotron img{
    width: 400px;
 }
.jumbotron h2{
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: verdana;
  }
```

Comment: Hi guys , is anyone tell me why it's couldn't working if i override it. SOS.....

Comment: Maybe this can help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727020/remove-padding-in-jumbotron-bootstrap-3

Comment: What happens when you increase the specificity of the overriding `.jumbotron` rule? For example like: `.top-header .jumbotron {margin-bottom:0px;}`

Comment: Yes, @AdamCalvetBohl is right. It can be bcos of the specification of the css selectors and the other thing is your override css file is declared before the original file in your html.

Comment: Hi guys, fixed , just included the "index.css" before "bootstrap.css".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like maybe you've included your "index.css" before the "bootstrap.css". If that is correct, swap them around so that your "index.css" is loaded last, not first.

eg;

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```